# How to write a migrate to undo the unique constraint in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, database-migration

I would do this to make my email field `unique` in the table.

`$table->unique('email');`

I've tried

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('contacts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropUnique('email');
    });
}
```

Then, when I run php artisan migrate, I got this

[image]

It tell me that it's not there, but I'm 100% sure that it's there.

[image]

How do write a migration to undo that ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have to do `$table->dropUnique('users_email_unique');`

> To drop an index you must specify the index's name. Laravel assigns a
>   reasonable name to the indexes by default. Simply concatenate the
>   table name, the names of the column in the index, and the index type.

Answer (score 68):

This the better way to drop unique. You can use the real column name here.

```
$table->dropUnique(['email']);
```